# Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier in render method reactjs

Tags: ruby-on-rails, reactjs, browserify, browserify-shim

I am using browserify rails and reactify and have the following component (pasted below). But, when I call it for rendering from a javascript file as shown in the second part below, I get the  following error at the return line of the render method. Can you kindly help and let me know what is wrong?

> Uncaught SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier error

**Component:**

```
/** @jsx React.DOM */

var React = require('react')
var Hello = React.createClass({
  render: function() {
   return <div>Hello, {this.props.name}</div>
  }
})
```

**Calling from JS file:**

```
var React = require('react');
var HelloMessage = require('alacalc/test_react');
```

Comment: Are you sure the reactification is occuring?

Comment: I think it is working, because it throws an error React not known if there is no pragma at the top. Is there any other convincing way to figure out if it is getting reactified

Comment: Look at the transformed file.